# Is it possible to use analogWrite() using an external Power Supply Unit?

Tags: arduino-nano, motor, analogwrite

As far as I know, my Arduino Nano can perform `analogWrite()` ranging from 0 to 1023 for 0 to 5 V respectively, but I want to control a DC motor which requires 9 V for good performance. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is possible.

`analogWrite()` sends out a 5 V PWM signal (3.3 V on some Arduinos) from a pin. You can't use this PWM signal to drive a motor directly; an Arduino IO pin can't deliver enough current for that.

You will have to get a separate 9 V power supply that can supply enough current for the motor, and use a BJT or MOSFET to switch that 9 V with the PWM signal from the Arduino, or use a dedicated motor driver IC or module.

There are plenty of schematics for this on the interwebs.